OpenSCAD import dpi setting
I'm importing an svg and extruding it. Here is the code:
translate([25,4,5]) rotate([90,0,0])
linear_extrude(height=5)
import("logo.svg",dpi=25.4);

According to the OpenSCAD User Manual, the DPI setting should scale the image. I've tried two different size logos and they show up the same so the size of the image does not seem to be a factor.
I get the exact same image regardless of what I set the dpi value to, except if I set it zero or other invalid number then it becomes huge. What gives? When I preview it works as expected except for the size. However nothing shows up when I render. Oh and the SVG file has two lines of text in it, but only one is showing up, but that isn't a huge deal. SVG file format isn't supported, so here is a png version of the SVG file I'm using.

You can find the actual SVG file here https://oruggt.net/logos/OruggtNet-bw-wide-slogan.svg
BTW all text has been converted to paths; there are no actual text objects in the SVG file.
